# Implementation of memmove

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

Here is my implementation of `memmove`; where can I improve?

```
void* memmove(void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count)
{
    char *dest_ = static_cast<char*>(dest), *src_ = (char*)(src);
    if ((char*)src + count > dest && src < dest) //
    {
        dest_ += (src_ += count - 1, count - 1);
        while (count--) *dest_-- = *src_--;
    }
    else while (count--) *dest_++ = *src_++;
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: I'll just leave [a link to interesting video](https://youtu.be/DAvZ3OG9cNo?list=PLzE2-LGSuSxvae4vEM8KLyoArMr1VWFKF) about C style casts. Not a secret, but when in a video, is much more engaging.

Comment: The biggest improvement is not to use it after you are done with the exercise. Remember why the question is tagged as it is.

Comment: If you use `unsigned char` rather than `char`, your function will be guaranteed safe if some of the source bytes are indeterminate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Missing header: `#include <cstddef>` is required for `std::size_t` (other headers also provide it).

There's no need for `src_` to cast away the constness of `*src`:

```
char *dest_ = static_cast<char*>(dest);
char const *src_ = static_cast<char const*>(src);
```

Personally, I'd just go for `d` and `s` rather than the ugly trailing underscores, but that's very much a matter of taste.

Arithmetic and comparison using `<` between pointers to different objects is unspecified behaviour; we could use `std::less` safely instead.  Or we could accept the unspecified result, because in the case where `src` and `dest` are in different objects, it doesn't matter which branch is taken.

There's no need to test for `src + count > dest` as well as `src < dest`; we can quite happily use the "reverse" copy for any lower-to-higher copy, as long as we don't subtract from `count==0` in that branch.

In the "reverse" branch, it's disingenuous to hide the assignment to `src_` inside the assignment to `dest_`.  Much clearer to write as two statements:

```
    src_ += count - 1;
    dest_ += count - 1;
```

We can avoid that `-1` if we pre-decrement rather than post-decrement (it's safe to point to one past the end).

Style: Use braces on both sides of `else`, or neither; avoid `if () {} else ;`.

---

### My version

```
#include <cstddef>

void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, std::size_t count)
{
    auto d = static_cast<char*>(dest);
    auto s = static_cast<char const*>(src);

    // If s and d are in distinct objects, the comparison is
    // unspecified behaviour, but either branch will work.
    if (s < d) {
        s += count;
        d += count;
        while (count--)
            *--d = *--s;
    } else {
        while (count--)
            *d++ = *s++;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

---

## Performance

Copying a single char at a time is going to be *sloowww*.  Real implementations take advantage of processors' native transfer size, DMA hardware, and specialized instructions where available.  That's why it's a standard library function rather than user-supplied.

Comment: Can you add a link to a common library implementation (edit: source code) that has hardware specific code paths? I'm sure this exists but am having a hard time getting good search results.

Comment: @BurnsBA: glibc's implementation is in `string/memmove.c`, and has specifics for word-by-word moving, and for page-table manipulation to move/copy large amounts of memory.

Comment: You know about [Enhanced REP MOVSB on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy)? Relying on the microcode can be superior to calling a library function.

Comment: [`std::less` yields a total order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) for any pointer type, even if `<` doesn't, so it may be preferable to use `std::less` to make it easier to reason about the program's correctness.

Comment: "Thankfully, in the case where src and dest are in different objects, it doesn't matter which branch you take"; mixing `far` and `huge` DOS pointers will hose this code; but you probably don't care.

Comment: I don't know anything about DOS, @Joshua, but are you suggesting that there's a case where the order matters and the pointers don't address (parts of) the same object?

Comment: @Joshua: Conversions from `huge` pointers to `far` pointers will cause far greater problems.  Among other things, if two `far` pointers are derived from two different `huge` pointers, applying the the comparison and difference operators to them will yield meaningless results, *even if both pointers identify parts of the same object*.

Comment: @BurnsBA: here's [glibc's memmove/memcpy implementation for x86-64, written in assembly (AT&T syntax)](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S.html#19).  The design-notes comment is pretty good, explaining the strategy for different sizes.  For short copies, it uses two potentially-overlapping loads from the start & end, then two stores.  This always works regardless of src/dst overlap, so it avoids checking anything but size for small copies, and is very good.

Comment: Different implementations of stuff like memcpy, strlen, and so on, are selected at dynamic-link time.  So for example they can use AVX2 on CPUs that support it, but only check once per process with no extra dispatch overhead beyond the existing indirection through a function pointer for calls into a shared library.

Comment: Perhaps I should also mention that most of the time, GCC's built-in implementation will be used; I expect that's true of other compilers (all compilers need one somewhere, e.g. for default copy of POD types).  I don't expect the library function to get much use.  And the built-in one has many implementations that can be emitted according to `-march` and `-mtune`.

Comment: @user2357112 Is it means the behavior `compare` itself is total ordering? e.g. : if (a, b) is comparable, (b, c) is comparable, then (a, c) is comparable && (a, a) is comparable && (a, b) is comparable, then (b, a) is comparable. Opposite, `less` itself is not total ordering form perspective of discrete math

Comment: Saw this again while looking for the link in my last comment :P  GCC's builtin memcpy inlines small sizes, but for sizes that aren't known at compile time it (almost?) always calls the library `memcpy`.  Possibly with profile-guided optimization you might see it choose to inline some code when the size at runtime turns out to always be small, but it's a good example of why letting the compiler see constants is very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Comparing pointers to unrelated objects [has unspecified result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086675).

Do not use C-style casts, or use them consistently everywhere. Instead, use a `static_cast<char*>(const_cast<void*>(src))`.

Do not use multiple assignments in a single statement (`dest_ += ...`), especially not in combination with the comma operator. This is only confusing and helps neither the human reader nor the compiler.

Remove the empty comment. It doesn't serve any purpose.

Instead of adding `count - 1`, you can add `count` and use pre-decrement. This is clearer code since you don't have a magic 1 lying around.

The cast in the condition can be replaced by just `src_`.

The whole condition should read `(src_ < dest_ && dest_ < src_ + count)` to match the common pattern for a *between* test.

Comment: I mistakenly claimed that the pointer comparison was *undefined*, but stole a correction from you - thanks and +1.